# Adding spring aop to methods of classes which doesn't override the parent class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have two classes

```
AbstractWorkFlow

ProductionWorkFlow
```

`AbstractWorkFlow` has fully implemented method `executeWorkFlow` which I haven't overridden in `ProductionWorkFlow`.

Now I'm adding a Spring AOP to the `ProductionWorkFlow.executeWorkFlow` method.

```
<aop:pointcut id="businessService"
         expression="execution(* ProductionWorkFlow.executeWorkFlow())" />
<aop:around pointcut-ref="businessService"  method="log"/>
```

But even though executionWorkFlow is executed, my aspect doesn't seem to be triggered. Any idea on this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the pointcut to be:

```
execution(* AbstractWorkflow+.executeWorkflow());
```

Your advice doesn't match because, since `ProductionWorkFlow` does not override `executeWorkFlow`, `execution(* ProductionWorkFlow.executeWorkflow())` does not exist.

If you really want to advise only `ProductionWorkFlow`, and not other implementations, then change it to:

```
execution(* AbstractWorkFlow+.executeWorkflow()) && target(ProductionWorkFlow);
```

Comment: Hi Romain , great answer, can we add multiple classes to the target say I have another class extending AbstractWorkFlow called DistributionWorkFlow how can I add in to target.

Comment: @Isuru you could use the following: `execution(* AbstractWorkFlow+.executeWorkflow()) && (target(ProductionWorkFlow) || target(DistributionWorkFlow));`. But really, if you want "all children of `AbstractWorkflow`" to be advised, just use my first code sample.